# How many championship rings does Troy Aikman have?

Tags: american-football, trivia, awards

As I was watching Green Bay beat up on Carolina today, I saw a [Papa John's Pizza ad](http://www.ispot.tv/ad/7MvN/papa-johns-fox-halftime-report-feat-troy-aikman) featuring Troy Aikman.  During the commercial, they show a closeup on his hand, bejeweled with his championship rings:

[image: Troy Aikman's ring hand]

[image]

Troy Aikman won three Super Bowls with the Dallas Cowboys, but I see six rings here.  How many championship rings does Troy Aikman have?

Comment: One of the rings looks like a class ring from some school he attended

Comment: Did Troy receive any rings while he was at UCLA? Their rings are blue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

He won three super bowls (92,93,95), plus a college football championship (while injured), in 1985.

He wasn't a member of any coaching staffs who won championships, as far as I can tell - he's been a commentator since his retirement, for Fox.

From looking at the picture, there are three superbowl rings, which would be his pinky finger, middle finger, and thumb.  There is one Pro Football Hall of Fame ring, which is the lower ring on his ring finger (the oval-shaped purple ring).  One would be his College Football Hall of Fame ring, which is likely the other ring finger ring.  The sixth could be one of a few things; it could be his college football championship ring, although that should be red.  It could be a ring for an MVP or some other honor, or possibly for the Dallas Cowboys Ring of Honor, though I didn't see any evidence of that existing.

Comment: He did win a national championship in college (though not as the starter), he also won 3 NFC championships.

Comment: Yes, but I don't see a ring that is clearly that ring: it's red, and I don't see a red ring, unless the color is very out of whack and one of the purplish ones is that.  I also can't confirm that he received a college championship ring - he wouldn't have been on the active roster, after all, and I don't know what the rules are for that sort of thing (though Wikipedia does list him as being on the championship team, but who knows what source that comes from).

Comment: @waxeagle There are rings for NFC championships?  That seems a little silly.

Comment: @BenMiller There are generally only rings for the losing superbowl team for their championship.  IE, last year the Seahawks would have gotten a superbowl ring and the Broncos would have gotten AFC Champion rings.

Comment: @Joe So the winners of the Super Bowl don't also get conference championship rings?  Then I guess Troy Aikman doesn't have any NFC championship rings.

Comment: Not as far as I know.  I looked, and found a page that showed [examples of all Superbowl rings](http://www.hoffco-inc.com/sb/rings.html) and [all conference championship rings](http://www.hoffco-inc.com/sb/rings-conf.html), and they always had only one conf. championship ring from each year - the loser.  So Jim Kelly did get four rings, just not the four he was hoping for. :)